# Node.js process.env.YOUR_VARIABLE returning undefined

Tags: javascript, node.js, dotenv

im trying to hide a discord token for my bot and im pretty sure i have dotenv setup correctly but all i get back is undefined. i even went so far as to use nodemon to restart the server when i make changes and still the same thing.

am i missing something? this is what i have tried so far.

```js
const dotenv = require('dotenv').config();
# and
require('dotenv').config();
```

```js
var token = process.env.DT;
#and
const token = process.env.DT;
```

```js
DT=yourtokenhere
```

Comment: where is your `.env` file?

Comment: it should be in my root directory. its sitting right next to my index.js file

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out. my code editor made it seem like it was in the same file as my index.js but it wasn't i feel dumb lol

Answer (score 0):

If you don't have the .env file in the root try specifying the path to the .env file like this:

```
require('dotenv').config({ path: '/custom/path/to/.env' })
```

Let me know if it wasn't the case.

Comment: ya same thing :/ i tried that already as well but i tried again just a second ago to sanity check and i still get undefined